# jqgrid option to show query

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Just saw there is an option in JQGrid which lets you see the query like this:

```
((Code = "5") AND (Response_Code NOT LIKE "5%") AND Response_Text = "" AND Notes = "")
```

i want to use this text and pass directly to server to get me the data based upon this condition, how can i do it, any idea, i tried using the inspector panel and directly use the class like this

```
'&Q=' + $(".queryresult tbody tr td.query").html()
```

but it is always sending `undefined` in the url call.

the `showQuery: true` is set at the `NavGrid`

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <= ver 4.7?

Comment: latest version of jqgrid Guriddo jqGrid

Comment: In this case I think it is a good idea to ask the Guriddo support or write a question in the [Guriddo public forum](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=4)